# PlotlyJS, position secondary x-axis below another x-axis

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a plotlyJS chart with multiple x-axis.

I want one x-axis to show tick labels every n minutes, and a further x-axis to show the tick labels every day.

I want the second x-axis (days) to be positioned below the minutes x-axis.

is this possible? So far I have:

```
function buildFixedLayout() {
    return {
        title: $("#qsName").val(),
        showlegend: false,
        xaxis: {
            showgrid: true,
            zeroline: true,
            autotick: false,
            dtick: 600000,
            showticklabels: false,
        },
        xaxis2: {
            autotick: false,
            dtick: 3600000,
            showticklabels: true,
            overlaying: "x",
            tickformat: "%H"
        },
        xaxis3: {
            autotick: false,
            dtick: 86400000,
            showticklabels: true,
            overlaying: "x",
            tickformat: "%a",
            anchor: "free",
            position: "0"

        },
        yaxis: {
            title: rxgDefRateAsPercentOfInsp,
            showline: true,
            showgrid: true,
            zeroline: true,
            fixedscale: true,
            fixedrange: true,
            range: [0, 10]
        },
        shapes: thresholdBackground(true)
    };
}
```

Which results in this being shown: (note the Thu) bit overlapping the minutes.

[image]
I think I need to anchor its position to the axis "x" with some offset, but I can't see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around. Set the ticklen and then set the tickcolor to white.

```
xaxis3: {
            autotick: false,
            dtick: 86400000,
            showticklabels: true,
            overlaying: "x",
            tickformat: "%a",
            ticklen: 15,
            tickwidth: 0,
            tickcolor: "#FFF"
        },
```

Produces:

[image]

Surely has to be a better way?